# sqlite error while running the below code

Tags: sqlite

```
SET SESSION sql_mode='ANSI,ORACLE';

CREATE TABLE walmart-detail
(
 Item_Identifier VARCHAR(200),
 Item_Weight VARCHAR(200),
 Item_Fat_Content VARCHAR(200),
 Item_Visibility VARCHAR(200),
 Item_Visibility VARCHAR(200),
 Item_Type VARCHAR(200),
 Item_MRP VARCHAR(200),
 Outlet_Identifier VARCHAR(200),
 Outlet_Establishment_Year VARCHAR(200),
 Outlet_Size VARCHAR(200),  
 Outlet_Location_Type VARCHAR(200),
 Outlet_Type VARCHAR(200),
 Item_Outlet_Sales VARCHAR(200)
 );
```

**error while running in mac**

> ```
> SQL Error [1]: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "-": syntax error)
>   [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "-": syntax error)
>   [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "-": syntax error)
> ```

Comment: Please learn about formatting for readability: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: `near "-": syntax error` sounds interesting. Did you try not using a "-" in table names? I.e. `walmart-detail` -> `walmart_detail`.

Comment: Enclose the table name inside square brackets `[walmart-detail]` or backticks or change the name to `walmart_detail`.  Also you have the column `Item_Visibility VARCHAR(200)` twice in the statement.

Answer (score -1):

You have two issues:-

**-** within an identifier is invalid unless enclosed e.g. you could have
:-

```
 [walmart-detial], 
 `walmart-detail`,
 "walmart-detail" or 
 'walmart-detail' but not 
 walmart-detail
```

.

Although perhaps **walmart_detail** would be a more consistent column name.

The second is that you have duplicated the definition of the **Item_Visibility** column, which if fixing the first error would result in a subsequent error.

As such you probably want to use :-

```
CREATE TABLE walmart_detail
(
 Item_Identifier VARCHAR(200),
 Item_Weight VARCHAR(200),
 Item_Fat_Content VARCHAR(200),
 Item_Visibility VARCHAR(200),
 Item_Type VARCHAR(200),
 Item_MRP VARCHAR(200),
 Outlet_Identifier VARCHAR(200),
 Outlet_Establishment_Year VARCHAR(200),
 Outlet_Size VARCHAR(200),  
 Outlet_Location_Type VARCHAR(200),
 Outlet_Type VARCHAR(200),
 Item_Outlet_Sales VARCHAR(200)
 );
```

Comment: Everything is answered in the comments.